# change multiple button color after multiple click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i change the button collor after click. i have one button and for the first click it will turn into red, the second time click it will turn into yellow, the third time it will turn into green, after three times click it will disabled.

```js
function apiBtn() {
  $('.btn-api').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      $clickCounts = 1;
    if ($clickCounts === 1) {
      $this.addClass('bg-act-red');
      $clickCounts += 1;
    } else if ($clickCounts == 2) {
      $this.addClass('bg-act-yellow');
      $clickCounts += 1;
    } else if ($clickCounts == 3) {
      $this.addClass('bg-act-green');
      $clickCounts += 1;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.btn-api {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.bg-act-red {
  background-color: #c5363a;
  color: white;
}
.bg-act-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: white;
}
.bg-act-green {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<span class="btn-api"> Change to on Proccess </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `$clickCounts` outside event handler. Also no need of `apiBtn()` function as you are using unobtrusive event handler.

```
var clickCounts = 1;
$('.btn-api').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($clickCounts === 1) {
        $this.addClass('bg-act-red');
        $clickCounts += 1;
    } else if ($clickCounts == 2) {
        $this.addClass('bg-act-yellow');
        $clickCounts += 1;
    } else if ($clickCounts == 3) {
        $this.addClass('bg-act-green');
        $clickCounts += 1;
    }
});
```

However if you have multiple button's, use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to store clicked count with element.

```
$('.btn-api')
    .data('clickCounts', 1) //Set defualt value
    .click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $clickCounts = $this.data('clickCounts');

        if ($clickCounts === 1) {
            $this.addClass('bg-act-red');
            $clickCounts += 1;
        } else if ($clickCounts == 2) {
            $this.addClass('bg-act-yellow');
            $clickCounts += 1;
        } else if ($clickCounts == 3) {
            $this.addClass('bg-act-green');
            $clickCounts += 1;
        }
        $this.data('clickCounts', $clickCounts);
    });
```

```js
$('.btn-api').data('clickCounts', 1).click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $clickCounts = $this.data('clickCounts')
  if ($clickCounts === 1) {
    $this.addClass('bg-act-red');
    $clickCounts += 1;
  } else if ($clickCounts == 2) {
    $this.addClass('bg-act-yellow');
    $clickCounts += 1;
  } else if ($clickCounts == 3) {
    $this.addClass('bg-act-green');
    $clickCounts += 1;
  }  
  $this.data('clickCounts', $clickCounts);
});
```

```css
.btn-api {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.bg-act-red {
  background-color: #c5363a;
  color: white;
}
.bg-act-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: white;
}
.bg-act-green {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn-api"> Change to on Proccess </span>
<span class="btn-api"> Change to on Proccess 2 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve it with a nice Switch Statement like this:

```
var $clickCounts = 1;

$('.btn-api').click(function() {
  switch ($clickCounts) {
    case 1:
      $(this).addClass('bg-act-red');
      $clickCounts++
      break;
    case 2:
      $(this).addClass('bg-act-yellow');
      $clickCounts++;
      break;
    case 3:
      $(this).addClass('bg-act-green');
      $clickCounts
      break;
  }
});
```